# How to detect application uniqueness in Rust using dbus

Tags: rust, dbus

How can I detect application uniqueness using the dbus crate(https://crates.io/crates/dbus) in Rust?

So far I've tried the following but the the function always returns false.

```rust
pub fn detect_uniqueness() -> Result<bool, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let conn = dbus::blocking::Connection::new_session()?;
    match conn.request_name("com.localserver.myapp", false, false, false) {
        Err(e) => Err(Box::new(e)),
        Ok(dbus::blocking::stdintf::org_freedesktop_dbus::RequestNameReply::Exists) => Ok(true),
        _ => Ok(false)
    }
}
```

---

Changing the function to the following indicates that the function always reaches `RequestReply::PrimaryOwner`.

```rust
pub fn detect_uniqueness() -> Result<bool, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let conn = dbus::blocking::Connection::new_session()?;
    match conn.request_name("com.localserver.myapp", false, false, false) {
        Err(e) => Err(Box::new(e)),
        Ok(dbus::blocking::stdintf::org_freedesktop_dbus::RequestNameReply::PrimaryOwner) => {
            log::info!("PrimaryOwner");
            Ok(true)
        },
        Ok(dbus::blocking::stdintf::org_freedesktop_dbus::RequestNameReply::InQueue) => {
            log::info!("InQueue");
            Ok(false)
        },
        Ok(dbus::blocking::stdintf::org_freedesktop_dbus::RequestNameReply::Exists) => {
            log::info!("Exists");
            Ok(false)
        },
        Ok(dbus::blocking::stdintf::org_freedesktop_dbus::RequestNameReply::AlreadyOwner) => {
            log::info!("AlreadyOwner");
            Ok(false)
        },
    }
}
```

I am not sure which of [these](https://docs.rs/dbus/0.7.1/src/dbus/blocking/stdintf.rs.html#16-21) implies application uniqueness.

I have tried holding off the first instance of the program if the function reaches `PrimaryOwner` and launch another instance, but even the second instance seems to reach `PrimaryOwner` too.

```rust
// main.rs
fn main() {
    aux::logger::init();

    if app::manually_invoked() {
        match app::unique_instance() {
            Ok(unique) => {
                if unique {
                    log::info!("Unique instance detected.");
                    loop {
                        std::thread::sleep_ms(999999);
                    }
                } else {
                    log::info!("Duplicate instance detected.")
                }
            },
            Err(e) => {
                log::error!("Error detecting uniqueness: {}.", e);
                app::exit();
            }
        }
    } else {
        // 
    }
}
```

```rust
// app.rs
pub fn manually_invoked() -> bool {
    std::env::args().len() == 1
}

pub fn unique_instance() -> Result<bool, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    crate::aux::ipc::detect_uniqueness()
}

pub fn exit() {
    std::process::exit(1);
}
```

Resulting into the program thinking that it's always unique.

Comment: Might be worth rearranging the function to provide more than just a boolean. What is the concrete output of the call to `request_name()`?

Comment: @E_net4theMeta-RemoveR, changing to https://pastebin.com/XLepk1jT indicates that it reaches RequestNameReply::PrimaryOwner. I'm not sure which of these(https://docs.rs/dbus/0.7.1/dbus/blocking/stdintf/org_freedesktop_dbus/enum.RequestNameReply.html) imply application uniqueness best.

Comment: I've not used D-Bus from Rust but looking at your code I'm guessing this happens: you always become the name owner and immediately after that the Session/Connection goes out of scope, resulting in name release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `dbus::blocking::Connection` goes out of scope, it will be dropped and result in [the underlying `dbus` connection](https://github.com/diwic/dbus-rs/blob/c4eccacacec64c87fd6de5e58fe9e201d4add3ad/dbus/src/channel.rs#L19) being dropped too.

In order to do anything meaningful with the connection, you need to keep it alive. One way to do that is to create connection once and pass the reference around:

```rust
//# dbus = "0.7.1"

use dbus;
use dbus::blocking::Connection;
use dbus::blocking::stdintf::org_freedesktop_dbus::RequestNameReply;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let conn = Connection::new_session()?;
    match is_unique(&conn) {
        Ok(true) => loop {},
        _ => Ok(()),
    }
}

pub fn is_unique(conn: &Connection) -> Result<bool, dbus::Error> {
    match conn.request_name("com.localserver.myapp", false, false, false) {
        Ok(RequestNameReply::PrimaryOwner) => Ok(true),
        Ok(_) => Ok(false),
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}
```

Try run the program twice and the second instance will terminate immediately.